# http::proxy module engine

Tags: perl, http, cpan

I have a question about this CPAN module http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Proxy/

it seems that this module support engines

Could someone explain me the difference between:

```
    use HTTP::Proxy;
    my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new( engine => 'NoFork' );
```

and :

```
    use HTTP::Proxy;
    my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new;
```

and:

```
   use HTTP::Proxy;
   my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new( engine => ScoreBoard );
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote from [HTTP::Proxy::Engine POD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Proxy/lib/HTTP/Proxy/Engine.pm)

> The role of an engine is to implement the main fork+serve loop with all the required bookkeeping. This is also a good way to test various implementation and/or try out new algorithms without too much difficulties.

The descriptions of various engines are:

HTTP::Proxy::Engine::Legacy - The "older" HTTP::Proxy engine
HTTP::Proxy::Engine::NoFork - A basic, non forking HTTP::Proxy engine
HTTP::Proxy::Engine::ScoreBoard -A scoreboard-based HTTP::Proxy engine

NOTE: The last one seems to be implementing a "Scoreboard" dynamic scheduling algorithm (which is usually used for CPU instruction sceduling). In this case it's much more simplified, and the scoreboard - from my glancing at the source - appears to be simply a list of statuses of each forked off child process

Comment: thanks for the answer ,could you explain what is scoreboard-based http::proxy engine and if non forking http::proxy engine is using threads?

Comment: @johnny2 - non-forking is DEFINITELY not using threads. I would strongly recommend that you follow the link to CPAN, and read the source code for non-forking one, it is a total of <50 lines of code that's farily simple and is a good excercise in understanding how an engine in HTTP Proxy is implemented.

Comment: @johnny2 - scoreboard-based engine - see my update in the answer.